# Display Linkedin article in an iframe

Tags: iframe, linkedin-api

I would like to display a Linkedin article in an iframe on my website but when I use the iframe, it is just displaying a blank page. Does Linkedin have make security for Iframes?
Is there something I can do to display an iframe like that?

This is my code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.linkedin.com/today/post/article/20130117141235-20017018-stop-using-these-16-terms-to-describe-yourself?trk=mp-details-rc" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"  > Don't work </iframe>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does Linkedin have make security for Iframes?

Yes, in a word. Look in your browser's error console and you'll see why it's not working:

```
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

LinkedIn has specifically disallowed third parties from iframing their content.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Frame-Options#Frame-Options